# non root user can not use -enable-kvm

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

One user in the `root` group and not in the `kvm` group. He can run `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm` with no problem. There is also another user that is not in the `root` group but he belongs to `kvm` group. However, he can not use `-enable-kvm` option! and gets

```
failed to initialize KVM: Permission denied
```

What is the fix to fix that?

Comment: Maybe kvm device is not kvm group owned? `chown root:kvm /dev/kvm` as root and then try to run `qemu` with your user that is member of kvm group.

Comment: Interesting... I did that. The user then ran `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-lvm` with success. Then he closed the opened qemu window and ran the command again. Then he received `permission denied`!!!

Comment: That happened cause the permission could been changed. Maybe if you create a `udev` rule to get this permission fixed: Create a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules` with the content `KERNEL=="kvm", NAME="%k", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"` and reload udev rules with the command(as root):  `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`. This will get this permisson permanent fixed for this device file, and you will be able to issue `--enable-kvm` permanently

Comment: Is `65-kvm.rules` a one liner?

Comment: yup. It will set the to allow reading from owner (`root`)  and group(`kvm`) to that device

Comment: Posted as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a misconfigured permission at `/dev/kvm` device. This should have a read permisson by the `kvm` group. Steps to solve:

1. Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules` as `root`
2. Put the following line inside this file: `KERNEL=="kvm", NAME="%k", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"`
3. Reload rules with `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`
4. With an user that is member of `kvm` group, try to execute `qemu` with the `-enable-kvm` option.

This was fixed a long time ago on Arch Linux([task 14165, April 2009](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/14165)). Maybe you should also report this issue to your distribution developer list.